# How to handle multiple Selected entires submitted to PHP scripts

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

suppose the html code snippet of a form is as simple as

```
<form action='test.php' method="post">
<select multiple="multiple" name="fruit">
<option value="apple">Apple</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
<button type="submit"> Enter </button>
</select>
</form>
```

My Question is what's the format of `$_POST['fruit']` while executing the PHP scripts? It does not looks like an array. Since `$_POST['fruit'][0]` and `$_POST['fruit'][1]` does not work for access. I am wondering how to access the submitted array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var_dump($_POST['fruit']);` to see your array structure and how you can access it.

```
<form action='test.php' method="post">
<select name="fruit[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="apple">Apple</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
</form>
```

With such markup your fruits should be inside `$_POST['fruit']` as intended.

Comment: "How to handle multiple Selected entires submitted to PHP scripts" he indeed need to have `multiple="multiple"` to select multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['fruit']` is not an array. It will contain the `value` of the item selected, specified in `<option value="apple">`